# Facebook identifier issue using graph-api , Facebook return different identifier in search and after login

Tags: facebook-graph-api, laravel

I am working in a laravel project in which i am integrating facebook and twiiter api using lusitanian package. When i do search for facebook page using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=david&type=page&limit=10 i get some basic infomation like

```
{
  "avatar":"my__page_image_path",
  "username":"Logiciel Solutions",
  "identifier":"662139753894064",
  "type":"facebook",
  "verified":"0"
}
```

From this information i have to use unique identifier for some use in future. The second thing  when i again get user basic information using

```
  $fb = $this->oauth->consumer( 'Facebook' );
  $user = json_decode( $fb->request('/me'), true );
```

then i get some user info like

```
Array
(
  [id] => 303734986477673
  [email] => rajnish.gupta@logsolutions.co.in
  [first_name] => LogicielPage
  [gender] => male
  [last_name] => Page
  [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/303734986477673/
  [locale] => en_US
  [name] => LogicielPage Page
  [timezone] => 5.5
  [updated_time] => 2014-10-16T10:31:12+0000
  [verified] => 
)
```

Now the problem is i want same identifier in both case but it is different. Can anybody suggest me where i am wrong or what i need to do to get same id in second case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, to be honest, but you are searching for a Page in your first call and you will get the correct IDs for that page for sure.

The second call (/me) has no relation to Facebook Pages, it´s for requesting data of the User profile for the authorized User. And you will only get "App Scoped IDs" for those.

In order to get data of the Pages in the search result, this is what you would need to do (i guess, because i don´t know Laravel):

```
$fb = $this->oauth->consumer('Facebook');
$page = json_decode($fb->request('/662139753894064'), true);
```

Comment: Thanks @luschn for your response. Yes you are right. But i don't have any option to use this id directly like $fb->request('/662139753894064'). I want if there any possibility to access page information using 303734986477673 id. Is there any way?

Comment: that is NOT a page, it is a user profile...not sure what exactly you want to do, to be honest. you are trying to do two completely different things there.